# For loop resulting in wrong output

Tags: python, list, for-loop

The code snippet below results in [5,7,18,23,50], why 5 is not getting removed from the resultant list?

```
list1 = [11, 5, 17, 18, 23, 50]  
not_needed = {11, 5}

for e in list1:
    if e in not_needed:
        list1.remove(e)
    else:
        pass

print(list1)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you do not need that `else` condition, it is redundant. A loop will always pass to the next iteration automatically.

Comment: Why not do something like :   `list1 = [x for x in list1 if x not in not_needed]`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understood the mistake of iterating through a list while mutating it at the same time. Having gone through the suggestions, i think three alternatives in the order of efficiency are a) use List Comprehension b) iterate through the non_needed set and not the main list c)  iterate through the original list but use another list to capture the selected items

Answer (score 4):

Because you are modifying the list as it is being iterated over.

- When you read the first item, it is `11` so it gets removed.
- When you read the second item, it is `17`, because the first item
  was removed. The item `5` is now the **new** first item and you never get
  to check it.

Answer (score 2):

Because once the 11 is removed, the 5 gets skipped during iteration. This is why you never iterate over a list and remove from it at the same time.

```
list1 = [11, 5, 17, 18, 23, 50]
not_needed = {11, 5}

for e in not_needed:
    list1.remove(e)

print(list1)
```

Gives:

```
[17, 18, 23, 50]
```

Comment: Few edge cases will break this: if a). there are duplicate numbers in list1. b). not_needed has numbers which already don't exist in list1

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension when looping over a list and modifying it at the same time.

```
list1 = [x for x in list1 if not x in not_needed]
list1
[17, 18, 23, 50]
```

Further details on this here:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/python-tutorial-list-comprehension-examples/

Answer (score 1):

This is because after first iteration item 11 is deleted and it goes for second index which becomes 17 in list [5,17,18,23,50]
The best way to rectify this is to take result list so that you dont have to mutate "list1"

```
list1 = [11, 5, 17, 18, 23, 50]
not_needed = {11, 5}
result = []
for e in list1:
    if e in not_needed:
        pass
    else:
        result.append(e)

print(result)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a `not in` condition there and just tell it to append when it isn't in the list, rather than tell it to `pass` when it is in the list and then tell it to append when it isn't?

Comment: Yes, i just added to tell you it does not need to be there in reference to the code post by @sasy as he has (else pass) in his code. But ideally you are right, if pass shouldnt be there

Answer (score 1):

**for loop in python runs on the indexes not on each element**.

When it finds 11 and removes it from list1, list1 becomes [5, 17, 18, 23, 50] but the loop is now on second element. So it misses 5 in the list.